# remove download button from wordpress elementor playlist

Tags: wordpress, elementor, playlist

in my wordpress page i use elementor and make playlist for videos
when video played, the download button will show and when pressed, start to download.
i dont want any user download that videos.

i use javascript code :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery("video").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('controlsList','nodownload');
    jQuery(this).load();
  });
});
```

but work for first video in my playlist, when selected other video, js not work and download button  are there and user can download video

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not disabling the download function per se but simply hiding the download button using CSS?

The code would be:

```css
.respective-class {
  display: none;
  }
```

or

```css
.respective-class {
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```